# Left-associative operators vs Right-associative operators

Tags: parsing, operators, operator-precedence, associativity

If we have an expression:

```
a $ b @ c
```

`$` is a left-associative operator, `@` is right-associative.
They have the same precedence.

How is this expression parsed?  As `(a $ b) @ c` or as `a $ (b @ c)`?

Comment: An actual C or C++ example would probably be more clear.

Comment: In what language? Your own? Well, don't do that then! It's an ambiguous grammar which doesn't have a single way to resolve.

Comment: It is determined by the compiler how to analysis the grammar tree.Reading <<Compilers principles, techniques, and tools>> will help you a lot.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Operators at the same precedence are all either right associative or all left associative so the problem doesn't arise.

Comment: Right, I should have been drunk to ask this. Since each language have different precedences, so there should be no standards of this. They are decided by the compiler designers. And a clever designer would Do like Dipstick said.

Comment: @RobertBean, no luckily they are decided by language designers and are standardized for each language. If this would be left to the compiler implementor, you never could write portable code.

Answer (score 12):

This is an excellent question.  While Dipstick is correct that in many languages, operator precedences and associativities are defined to avoid such a problem, there are languages in which such a situation may arise.

Haskell is such a language.  It allows you to define your own infix operators, and their precedences (integer from 0 to 9) and associativity (left, right, non).  It's easy to create the preconditions for the scenario you described:

```
infixl 5 $$
($$) :: Int -> Int -> Int
a $$ b = a + b

infixr 5 @@
(@@) :: Int -> Int -> Int
a @@ b = a * b
```

And then the situation itself:

```
uhoh = 1 $$ 2 @@ 3
```

This results in this error message:

```
Precedence parsing error
    cannot mix `$$' [infixl 5] and `@@' [infixr 5] in the same infix expression
```

Of course, Haskell's solution -- aborting with a parse error -- is not the only way to deal with this problem, but it is certainly a reasonable one.

For more information about operator parsing in Haskell, please see section 4.4.2 of [the Haskell report](http://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/decls.html).